# casting char* to char**

Tags: c, casting

I am having a tough time understanding the following piece of code:

```
int stride = 512;
int max_len = 1024 * stride; 
char *addr = (char *)malloc(max_len);
for (int i=stride; i<max_len; i += stride)
    *(char **)&addr[i-stride] = (char*)&addr[i];
*(char **)&addr[i-stride] = (char*)&addr[0];
```

Looking at the code it seems this is trying to create some kind of circular link list. But I have no clue what those casts are actually doing.

Comment: Any chance you can get whoever wrote that code fired?

Comment: I agree with the answer, the code is 'bogus'. Someone did not really know what they were doing, and eventually just happened to make it work.

Comment: This is a sure candidate for obfuscated code contests http://www.ioccc.org/

Comment: friends, this piece of code is used in a standard benchmarking code and is developed by very experienced programmers. As Basile said, the authors may have had their reasons.

There is one typo which I introduced in the above code: "int i" must be declared before the for loop.

Comment: @blue_whale:  I don't care how "experienced" they are; there is no excuse for writing this code under any circumstances whatsoever.  Even assuming you have a reason for packing your circular structure into an array (which you don't), C has this little thing called a "struct" that can contain pointers to itself (see Basile's answer).  In other words, the exact same effect can be achieved in a portable and type-safe way.  This code is garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO the code you present is poor taste.

`*(char **)&addr[i-stride] = (char*)&addr[0];`  is taking the pointer `addr` to some dynamically allocated zone (right part `(char*)&addr[0]` could have been written `addr` which is simpler), then copying that address to the memory located at position `addr[i-stride]`.

This actually could be wrong (undefined behavior), e.g. when `&addr[i-stride]` (which could be written `addr+i-stride`) is not word aligned on some processors. In your case `i` happens to be `max_len` and `stride` happens to be 512, so that address is word aligned (since `malloc` gives a well aligned zone).

The original author of the code should perhaps have declared a `struct` (or maybe a `union`) like e.g.

```
 struct buffer_st {
    struct buffer_st* next;
    char content[];
 };
```